# What is the path when using Team Foundation Version Control (TFVC) as the VCS for a Jenkins project?

Tags: jenkins, azure-devops

I'm trying to connect a Jenkins project to a Visual Studio Team Services repository.

If I use the "Git" option for the VCS in the configurations (as I've seen in most tutorials), I get authentication issues, and entering my credentials does not remedy the error. If I use the "Team Foundation Version Control" option, it accepts the repository URL without any errors, but it asks me for the "project path."

So, my question is actually twofold:

- (1) Since Team Foundation is now known as Visual Studio Team Services, is this option depreciated and thus not worth using in my configuration anyway? I haven't even seen it or heard it mentioned as an option in any tutorial I've gone through, so I'm not sure if it's even used anymore (I thought my version of Jenkins was current, but I guess it might not be, somehow.) If this option is outdated, what is the preferred method now?
- (2) What is the "project path" that it is asking for? It says it must start with $/, so I'm not sure if that means it's the path to the project in the file system of the environment it's going to be running in (in my case, on a slave machine), or if it's referring to its path in the Visual Studio Team Services system or what exactly.

I've attached a screenshot below for reference. Any and all advice will be appreciated.

[Jenkins VCS config screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJ5NU.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding git authentication issue, you can use [Personal Access Token](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/team-services/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate) (username can be anything, such as test) or Alternate Authentication Credentials. The same as TFVC.

Regarding the path, it is the server path of TFVC

1. Go to Code page of team project
2. Select Files tab
3. Select a folder
4. Get the path

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the very helpful reply. This answered my question about the path and had good info on the credentials. I'm still getting a "Resource not available for anonymous access" error when I try to connect though, so I'm wondering if I need higher admin privileges or something? I am using a personal token as described in the link you provided-- I tried it as a username/password combo and as a secret text credential (the former returns that error and the latter won't even show up as an option.) Do you happen to know what this means?

Comment: UPDATE: The username field for my company was set to something other than the one I normally use, so that seems to have been the issue with my credentials. Thanks again!